# How to pick middle string which is consistent

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data which is consistent need to pick up a specific string

sample data :

```
Declare @v varchar(MAX) = '
 THEN ''ERC'' ELSE ''UNKNOWN'' END As Name,
            max(dt) as Effective_dt
            from M_stg.Employee_zone z 
            left join SD.ods.r_country r on ''.'' + r.country__code = right(z.EMP,3) and r.IND = 1'
```

How can I pick only

**Employee_zone**

from that entire string I have tried

this way

```
select LTRIM(RTRIM(PARSENAME(REPLACE (SUBSTRING(@v,CHARINDEX('FROM',@v),LEN(@v) ),'',' '),2)))
```

suggest me

Comment: SELECT 'Employee_zone'; -- :-)

Comment: @Morten what it mean I need to add anything in query

Comment: Your question makes no sense, can you improve it?

Comment: Can you maybe show more than one example string?

Comment: Are you trying get the table name out of a query? Does the schema never change?

Comment: @JeremyJ. yes exactly

Comment: @AaronBertrand this way I have tried can you suggest the other

Comment: your variable will result in an error, because of the internal quotes.

Comment: @scsimon I think there are more important issues than syntax with this one!  :)

Comment: @scsimon I just gave sample data and don't bother about quotes

Comment: if you can't give sample data that doesn't error out, i have little faith that your question is complete or that you have given enough details.

Comment: PARSENAME is returning a null, which indicates one of the following conditions is true:
Either object_name or object_piece is NULL.
A syntax error occurs.

Comment: PARSENAME is returning null because you are passing it the last two lines of your sample, not just the schema_name.object_name. In addition, the argument 2 gets schema name back. 1 gets object name back. If you use the answer that Tab Alleman just posted, you don't need PARSENAME.

Answer (score 2):

Use CHARINDEX functions to locate:

the `from` substring with whitespace on either side

the `.` character after the `from`

the next whitespace after the `.`

And get the substring between the last 2 charindexes.

Comment: I like seeing answers like this, they're helpful without providing a free code writing service (+1)

Comment: @MJH I'm not newbie to entirely depend on your answers I just gave sample data and lot more things to add that one..so please don't think here we are doing charity ...SO is all about learning and sharing

Comment: @mohan111 I can see you are not a newbie, your reputation is a good marker for that.  My comment was not aimed at you so please don't take any offence to it, I see very similar questions every day where people have not bothered to do a simple web search and would rather post a lazy question knowing that someone will give them a free answer without them having to do any of the work.  Again, that is not aimed at you, but there are lots of questions about extracting a string from within a string out there.  A good, well researched question will get a lot more help (and sympathy) than a bad one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve the table name from the hard coded string, try the below:

```
select left(right (@v, len(@v)-(charindex('M_stg.', @v)+len('M_stg.')-1)),charindex(' ',right (@v, len(@v)-(charindex('M_stg.', @v)+len('M_stg.')-1))) -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do NOT think the following is pretty, but it does the job:

```
select SUBSTRING(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@v, CHARINDEX('FROM', @v)+4, LEN(@v))),
CHARINDEX('.', LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@v, CHARINDEX('FROM', @v)+4, LEN(@v))))+1,
CHARINDEX(' ',
SUBSTRING(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@v, CHARINDEX('FROM', @v)+4, LEN(@v))),
CHARINDEX('.', LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@v, CHARINDEX('FROM', @v)+4, LEN(@v))))+1, LEN(@v)))-1)
```

assuming that you want the first table name occurring after the first FROM clause in your string, and that the table name is followed by a space (not a TAB character).